# How to change content of a modal dynamically in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to update the modal content whenever user checks a radio button.

```
     const Furnace = ({}) => {
      return (
          <View>
            <Text>Furnace</Text>
          </View>
        )
       }

 const TestScreen = (props) => {
   let Details = <View />;

   const changeOptions = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 0:
        Details = Furnace;
        return Details;
        break;
      case 1:
        Details = AC;
        return Details;
        break;
    }
   }

 return(
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => changeOptions(0)} />
      <Modal
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
              <Details/>
          </View>
      </Modal>
   </View>
 });
```

this method is not working and returns this error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a        class/function (for composite components) but
> got: object.

Comment: What is `Details` and how is it imported? What is `return Furnace`? Your switch case has multiple `return`s.

Comment: I updated the question, I know the code is confusing, but i just want to show you what I need exactly to do

Answer (score 1):

If `View` is a function, then `<View />` is like `View()`. So when you have:

```js
let Details = <View />;
```

`Details` here is the result of calling `View()`. but down in your `return` you again do this:

```js
<View style={styles.modalView}>
  <Details />
</View>
```

At this point `Details` is not a function/component anymore hence the error you're receiving. Do this instead:

```js
const TestScreen = (props) => {
  let Details = View; // <= HERE

  const changeOptions = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 0:
        Details = Furnace;
        return Details;
        break;
      case 1:
        Details = AC;
        return Details;
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <button onPress={() => changeOptions(0)} />
      <Modal>
        <View>
          <Details />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Guessing you're doing react native, here's what I came up with in few minutes:

```
function Details({ text }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default function TextScreen() {
  let [option, setOption] = React.useState(0);
  let [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={() => setVisible(true)} title='Open' />
        <Button onPress={() => setOption(0)} title='Show Furnace'/>
        <Button onPress={() => setOption(1)} title='Show AC'/>
      </View>
      <Modal visible={false} onRequestClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
        {option === 0 && <Details text='furnace' />}
        {option === 1 && <Details text='AC' /> }
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See it [here](https://snack.expo.io/p0Ol_Hkx-)

Comment: the error is gone but I get empty modal now

Comment: @Nima, I don't know what `View` or `Details` are. If you don't show it I can't help you more.

Comment: you can find the Furnace Component in the question , I need Details = Furnace. I really don't know this is a correct approach or not but I could not find any other way.

Comment: @Nima, updated the answer assuming that you're doing react-native

Comment: Thanks it makes more sense now